# dynamic text box and append and save them to sql server DataBase

Tags: c#, asp.net

HI I have requirement that 
1) display given no.of textboxes dynamically and save to DB
2) if I change the number then new textboxes should append to UI

EX: TextBox  AddButton

If I give 2 in textbox and click on add
Then 2 textboxes should appear. I filled some data in those textboxes. Now When I change the value 2 to 5 then 3 more textboxes should append(condition:old textboxes data should retain)
If the second value is less than or equal to first value then do nothing.

My code is

```
 void Append()
    {
        string Data = string.Empty;
        TextBox tb;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(hdnCnt.Value) < Convert.ToInt32(txtNoofGames.Text))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(txtNoofGames.Text); i++)
            {
                if (i <= Convert.ToInt32(hdnCnt.Value))
                {
                    tb = (TextBox)Form.FindControl("txtGame1");
                    Data = tb.Text;
                }
                TextBox Newtb = new TextBox();
                Newtb.ID = "txtGame" + i;
                Form.Controls.Add(Newtb);
                if (i <= Convert.ToInt32(hdnCnt.Value))
                {
                    Newtb.Text = Data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (hdnCnt.Value != "")
            Append();
        hdnCnt.Value = txtNoofGames.Text;
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt16(txtNoofGames.Text); i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "txtGame" + i;
            Form.Controls.Add(tb);
        }
    }
```

I am getting exception "object reference not set to an instance of object" at  Data = tb.Text; in append method.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize it from the looks of it

```
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
```

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Form.Controls.Add(tb);

Please try with Page.Form.Controls.Add(tb);